# Мигание кнопки

Tags: c#

Здравствуйте, нужно реализовать простую задачу: кнопка меняет цвет на некоторое время
(< 1 сек.) а потом возвращается в исходный цвет. Я пробовал следующее:

```
button1.BackColor = Color.Green;
System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(500);
button1.BackColor = Color.Transparent;
```

Но почему-то ничего не работает. Заранее спасибо.

Comment: чтобы мигала кнопка останавливать работу всей программы - круто!=)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
button1.BackColor = Color.Green;

var dt = new DispatcherTimer();

dt.Interval = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(500);
dt.Tick += delegate
{
    button1.BackColor = Color.Transparent;
    dt.Stop();
};

dt.Start();
```